# Why does AngularJS throw bad augmentation error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep getting error when i change scr code file of angular in src link from 1.2.2 to 1.5.0 i.e. code works prefectly fine with 1.2.2 but i get this error if I change it to 1.5.0 . I want to update it to 1.5.0 what can I do I mean what updates in the code needs to be done to make it compatible with angular 1.5.0

```
        Error: ng:areq
        Bad Argument
        Argument 'Controller_index' is not a function, got undefined
        Description
        AngularJS often asserts that certain values will be present and truthy using a helper function. If the assertion fails, this error is thrown. To fix this problem, make sure that the value the assertion expects is defined and truthy. I know 1.2.2 is outdated but I am using the same thing and I don't know whats new in 1.5.0 and how to change it.As per my knowledge it looks fine to me.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means you have not registered `Controller_index` as a controller. Try adding:

```
module.controller('Controller_index', Controller_index);
```

This was a [breaking change between 1.2 and 1.3](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3).

Comment: Thanx a lot been away long time from angular need to catch up